# Is this particular Student-t Distribution defined for a realization of standard deviation which is equal to zero?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given the student-t distribution:
$$
 T  =  \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{S/\sqrt{N}}
$$
where $S$ is the Sample Standard Deviation, I wonder if this distribution is defined for $S=0.$ Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The test statistic is indeed not defined if $S=0$. But this only comes up if either $N=1$ (at which point the $t$ distribution itself isn't defined) or if $N>1$ and all data points are identical (which, assuming independent continuously distributed data, has probability zero).

Comment: But how do they know it is a student-t distribution if its not defined on S=0? They exclude that possibility?

Comment: Strictly speaking the thing that is Student's $t$ distributed is that quantity when $X_i$ are iid normal random variables with mean $\mu$ and some common variance $\sigma^2$. In this case, if $N>1$, $P(S=0)=0$. If $X_I$ are not normally distributed then that quantity is not exactly Student's $t$ distributed for finite $N$, so $P(S=0)$ could be positive. (But if $X_i$ are iid and nondegenerate then $P(S=0)$ decays exponentially with $N$.)

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally one has
\begin{align}
& X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \text{i.i.d} \operatorname N(\mu,\sigma^2) \\[8pt]
& \overline X = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n \sim \operatorname N(\mu,\tfrac{\sigma^2} n) \\[8pt]
& S^2/\sigma^2 = \big( (X_1-\overline X)^2 + \cdots + (X_n-\overline X)^2\big) \sim \chi^2_{n-1} \\[8pt]
& \frac{\overline X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n} \sim \operatorname N(0,1) \\[8pt]
& \frac{\overline X-\mu}{S/\sqrt n} \sim t_{n-1}
\end{align}
In this scenario, the probability that $S=0$ is $0$ unless $\sigma=0,$ so there is no need to consider that.

If you apply this to samples from a discrete distribution rather than to a normal distribution, then there is nonzero probability that $S^2=0.$

- Is the value of the random variable defined for $S=0$? Not unless one might have some reason to say it is $\infty$ or something like that.
- Is the **distribution,** defined in that case? Certainly even in the case of the normal distribution, one would not define a t-distribution for any particular value of $S$, unless one speaks of a **conditional** distribution **given** a particular value of $S.$ There is the question of the asymptotic distribution as $n\to\infty,$ and if the population distribution is continuous, I think that's been examined in published papers. I don't know about the discrete case though.

Comment: so basically the distribution is different for discrete case?

Comment: @bonez001 In general, the distribution of this test statistic will only be *asymptotically* Student's $t$ distributed for large $N$, when you draw iid samples from a nondegenerate distribution other than $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: @bonez001 : It is only with discrete distributions that the probability is more than $0$ that $S^2=0$  with $n>1.$ and even with discrete distributions (except the "delta distribution" which has variance $0$) the probability that $S^2=0$ goes to $0$ as $n$ grows. $\qquad$